# Use single ftplugin for more than one filetype

Tags: filetype

I have an ftplugin under `&runtimepath/ftplugin/c.vim` which sets all my preferred options for c files.  However, I would also like to use the same settings for `cpp` files.  I could just copy the settings over, but that seems redundant.  Is there a way of loading an ftplugin for more than one filetype?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The default ftplugin (`/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/cpp.vim` on my system) should already do this:

```
" Only do this when not done yet for this buffer
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif

" Behaves just like C
runtime! ftplugin/c.vim ftplugin/c_*.vim ftplugin/c/*.vim
```

`runtime` should be relative to the `runtimepath`:

> There can be multiple `{file}` arguments, separated by spaces.  Each `{file}` is
>   searched for in the first directory from `'runtimepath'`, then in the second
>   directory, etc.

If I create a `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`, this also gets executed for C++ files without doing anything!

If you don't have this file in your Vim version,, you can create a new `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim` file with the `runtime!` statement.

---

Or, if you're on a UNIX-y system you can use a symlink:

```
$ ln -s ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim ~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp.vim
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that!  Good observation.  I would use the runtime solution if I needed this for other filetypes.

Answer (score 2):

Within cpp.vim put:

```
source <sfile>:h/c.vim
```

`<sfile>` expands to the currently sourced file, and `:h` means the head of it.

Comment: There is nothing to do. As Martin explained, C ftplugins are automatically sourced for C++ buffers

Comment: More for other readers, e.g. make .scss handled same was as .css etc

Comment: Then, unless you want to load a very specific file, IMO, `:runtime! ftplugin/css*.vim ftplugin/css/*.vim` would be a better solution.