# enable NERDTree only when editing h/c/cpp files

Tags: vimrc

```
if (&filetype=='c' || &filetype=='cpp' || &filetype=='h')
  autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
  autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p

  " class outline viewer : F8
  nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
endif
```

I tried this vimrc script, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but I think `VimEnter` is called before `&filetype` is set so that `if` is never executed. Try:

```
augroup C
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c,cpp NERDTree | wincmd p | nmap <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
augroup END
```

Better to write an filetype plugin (see `:h ftplugin`). For example I have a file in `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` with this content:

```
autocmd BufReadPost,BufWritePost <buffer> Accio eslint
autocmd InsertLeave,TextChanged <buffer> call semhl#highlight()
autocmd FileType javascript call semhl#highlight()
nnoremap <buffer> <C-]> :TernDef<cr>
```

These auto-commands and the mapping are only available for JavaScript files. I don't know how to call an `ftplugin` for both C and C++, but the content would be something like:

```
autocmd FileType c,cpp NERDTree | wincmd p
nmap <buffer> <F8> :TagbarToggle<CR>
```

If you use Vim the location of this file would be `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`.

## Edit

According to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3178/786) you can use symbolic links or source your `c.vim` ftplugin from your `cpp.vim` plugin (or vice versa).