# common /after/syntax for different file types

Tags: filetype, syntax

I want some common syntax highlighting for various filetypes.

Currently I have `runtimepath/after/syntax/base.vim`
which has syntax rules I want and then I created mklink (this is windows) to `base.vim` for all filetypes (eg javascript.vim, c.vim, etc) that I want to have same `/after` processing.

In this way single edit (in base.vim) will have effect in all filetypes I want to propagate to.

Above works, but is there a better way to do it?

Comment: [This question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/use-single-ftplugin-for-more-than-one-filetype) is related, I think

Comment: Hi, welcome here. I think you should try to make your post more readable. Try to use the simple `markdown syntax` the site offers, as well as more new lines. This will increase your chance of getting answers :)

Answer (score 1):

If in specific you would like to avoid the `mklink` on Windows or symlinks on Linux/Unix/Mac, you can use small files for the specific languages that simply load `base.vim`.

The technique is recommended in [`:help :syn-files`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Asyn-files):

> When a language is a superset of another language, it may include the other one,
>   for example, the `cpp.vim` file could include the `c.vim` file:
>
> ```
> :so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim
> ```

In your case, to source file `base.vim` from the same directory where the language file is located, you can use:

```
source :h/base.vim
```

As the whole contents of files `javascript.vim`, `c.vim`, etc. in your `$HOME/vimfiles/after/syntax/`.

If the name `syntax/base.vim` is unique, you can also use the [`runtime`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aruntime) command to load it, which will search the file in the directories listed under `'runtimepath'`:

```
runtime syntax/base.vim
```

Or if you want to load *all* files named `syntax/base.vim` in directories listed under `'runtimepath'`, then use `runtime!` instead.

Comment: `runtime` would work equally well, no?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes. I updated the answer to include an option using `:runtime`. The one caveat with `:runtime` is that the name `syntax/base.vim` needs to be quite unique (or you're willing to source all of them), so I think personally I still lean towards the `:source` approach in this particular case.

Comment: @filbranden♦ This is good, thx. More in line with Vim design than mklink

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mysyntaxfile` hook. E.g.

```
" in vimrc
let g:mysyntaxfile = '~/vimfiles/after/syntax/base.vim'
syntax on
...

" in base.vim
autocmd Syntax javascript,c call DoWhatever(expand('<amatch>'))
```

Note that you don't need `augroup` and stuff, as `synload.vim` manages syntax files by its own.

Comment: [`:help synload-2`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#synload-2) says: *"Source the user's optional file, from the `mysyntaxfile` variable. This is for backwards compatibility with Vim 5.x only."* [`:help mysyntaxfile`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#mysyntaxfile) basically covers creating a new file named after a filetype under the `syntax/` directory, so I imagine that's the preferred approach these days.

Comment: @filbranden I think there's a good reason to put it to use it if it saves us a dozen of similar edits.

Comment: @Matt: And while you can use au's in base vim, one can also have usual syntax commands as well, eg 
syn keyword someSyntax someKWord
right?

Comment: @GiorgiShonia In Vim there's no real difference between "colorschemes", "sessions", "syntaxes" etc. They all are just VimScript.

Comment: @GiorgiShonia In fact, the main reason why we can't just trap into `autocmd Syntax x,y,z` is because we should play nicely with `syntax on/off`